# Help identifying a plastic pipe at the base of the house

Tags: plumbing, outdoor, uk

Last year I removed a patio because all of its deck was rotten, underneath I found a pipe - pictured.

Now I want to lay a concrete base for brick steps because the drop from the door was way to high. I wanted to make the steps wide enough to cover the unsightly pipe, but I don’t know whether I should and if it safe to do.

After taking off the bend it looks like the pipe leads straight under the house and there is nothing visible there.

I’m located in UK if that helps and the house is a mid-terraced one, built in 2006.[image: pipe]

Comment: Well it's clearly draining something, look at all that sediment! The next time it rains you should check if this pipe is draining water.

Comment: You should really figure out where that pipe goes.  Maybe it drains water from the roof into the gravel bed in the picture.  Then you wouldn't want to cover it in concrete.  Maybe it's a disused sewer pipe.  Then you would want to seal it up.  Maybe it's an active sewer vent and is meant to extend up to the roof line.  Then you would want to fix it.  If you have, or don't have, a basement that might help rule out some possibilities.

Comment: I feel like the majority of mystery pipe questions come from the UK.  I feel like it might be the country of mystery pipes.

Comment: Is there a "crawl space" under the house or is this a slab on grade?  Was the 90 deg bend originally pointed down? This looks like drain pipe to prevent ground water from collecting under the house. You cannot cover this up. Does water pool under the house after a heav vrain?

Comment: Thanks for the comments but I really doubt it drains anything, it has been always dry and the “sediment” you see is just dust that got in there during last year disassembly, digging, putting turf and now digging again

Comment: The bend was pointing horizontally - to the left. There was no crawl space or basement - answering someone above. Could I perhaps surround the pipe with concrete but leave soil/gravel underneath it, and cover it with some sort of grille? That’s the best idea that comes to mind right now

Comment: Incidentally the most similar build of pipe I've seen in western Canada is a giant 24" version with similar fittings.  It was used for main drain lines and the main line for a weeping tile system for an institutional building.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the pipe is, but the safe way is to extend the pipe to the outside of the concrete steps. You might want to wrap the embedded pipe in felt paper so it wouldn't adhere to the concrete in case you need to re-expose it.

Comment: I agree with r13 we don’t know the reason for the drain it may be there to drain a seasonal spring. (I have found this problem on several houses I built, no problem in the summer , property passed the septic percolation and soil inspection, but the first winter a spring developed and we had to add drainage beyond the original rock and foundation drains.

Answer (score 1):

Shove a camera on a stick up that baby and see what you learn. They're called "inspection cameras" and you can get super cheap USB ones for your phone or laptop that you can attach to a stiff wire to fish the pipe, or you can buy a more durable pipe fishing cam. If they're expensive where you live, check for rentals or call the local plumbing companies and ask for a quote. No sense wondering when it's not expensive to find out. Don't expect endurance from them but you can find super cheap inspection cams on Aliexpress.

There is no reason to wonder and risk a thousand currency mistake when finding out will cost between 20 and 200 currency.